# How to store country and state in sql server

Tags: sql-server, database, normalization

I'm creating a video website that similar to youtube except its targets the indie gaming community.

I'm working on the table design and have run into a bit of stumbling block with the location column.

How do major sites design tables for storing location?

`Profile` table:

```
ID | username | country | state
0  | jack     | US      | New York
1  | ted      | Canada  | Alberta
```

OR

```
ID | username | countryID
0  | jack     | 1
1  | ted      | 2
```

`Regions` table:

```
ID | country | state
0  | United States | Texas
1  | United states | New york
2  | Canada        | Alberta
```

Or is there some other design I missed?

Comment: I hate that you are storing the username and it isn't a user_id column or another identifier. Most designs will denormalize locations to the point of keeping it locations(country, state_province, city, zip). So your profile table would be (ID, username, site_id).

Comment: ID is the primary key for my tables. Im not using username as a primary key, is that what your saying? What is the site_id column used for?

Comment: Sorry, `site_id` would correlate to your `ID` column in the `regions` table. Excuse the last part I kind of misread but it does beg another question, your profile table is the primary users table? What if a user changes their profile or is that a 1:1 permanent connection?

Comment: no worries, Its a 1 to 1 relationship they can only have one location

Comment: But can a `user` only have 1 `profile`?

Comment: yes thats correct only 1 profile per user

Answer (score 10, accepted):

And what about :

```
profile Table
ID | username | stateID
0  | jack     | 1
1  | ted      | 2

states table
ID | countryID | state
0  | 0 | Texas
1  | 0 | New york
2  | 1 | Alberta

countries table
ID | country
0  | United States
1  | Canada
```

Comment: I think thats the best solution. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea how "big" websites handle their data, but anyway I think this would be a matter of preference and business requirements, in the first case the table isn't properly normalized as the state depends on the country, and in the other case the model is [almost] properly normalized (the country could be moved to another table). The first option can be faster when doing lookups et cetera but as it breaks the normalized relational model it can lead to issues when inserting/updating the data (as well as additional storage). Personally I would chose to use the second option (and maybe de-normalize it for analytics processing if needed - I would think it very much depends on the amount of data you expect to handle)

A normalized model would look something like:

```
profile (**username**, state)
states (**state**, country)
countries (**country**)
```

The example above doesn't use surrogate keys and only illustrate the model; a database implementation of the model would often use surrogate keys such as UserID, StateID and CountryID although if properly normalized they shouldn't be needed as the entities should be primary keys (as they are candidate keys).

Comment: isn't the second option technically not normalized as well cause the country is repeated?

Comment: Agreed. I think denormalizing things like location data is pretty standard. Country names don't change _that_ much but it is worth noting in case you need to enter "USA" and it needs to be "United States of America" then you're looking at a multi-thousand update statement.

Comment: @LeslieJones Ah yes, I guess I wrote that a bit too fast. You're right, the countries should be stored in another table for the normalization to be complete.

Comment: So I guess for perfect normalization there would be a countries table and another table of regions.

Comment: @jpw, even with the countries in another table its **still** not normalized. Example: United States -> State of Michigan -> County of Oakland -> City of Madison Heights -> Zip 48071-9999. The 48 in the zip refers to the state, 0 would refer to the routing facility, 71, would refer to the local PO, and -9999 would refer to the block. This gets a little crazy and its pretty normal to de-normalize in this situation.

Comment: @LeslieJones Indeed, much like the example in the answer by Fabien TheSolution. In a normalized model each table (or relation) should only contain information about one entity, although sometimes the process of denormalization can get to far and produce models that are impractical.